# Changing player turn order

Tags: belfort

In Belfort I find it confusing when turn order is changed.  Do you immediately swap turn markers during the placement phase?  Do the turns take effect immediately (still in the placement phase) or do you wait until the actions phase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The changing of player order is accomplished via use of the Kings Camp. During Placement phase, players can place a worker in the Kings Camp. The first player to play a worker in the Kings Camp puts the worker on the space with the "1" on it. The second player puts their worker on the space with a "2". Each player may only place the maximum of 1 worker in the Kings Camp.

Resolution of player order then occurs in the next phase (as part of the Collection phase). The first player to place then gets to decide which player order they want to be. If they already control the number they wanted, they simply turn it over (to the gray side). Otherwise, they switch their crest with another player and then turn their crest over to the gray side. NOTE: the player whose crest was swapped remains with the colored side up.

If a second player had a worker in the Kings Camp, they now can swap with any player except the player who's crest has the colored side up (i.e. they can't claim the crest # from the player who went before them in the Kings Camp). This continues until all players in the Kings Camp have had an opportunity to act.

After the Collections phase ends, all players now turn their crests so that the colored side is facing up. Now the Action phase now begins. However the order of this phase is determined by the player order as shown on the crests. Thus the player with the crest #1 now acts first, taking all of their actions, followed by the player with crest #2, etc.

This new player order will also be in effect during the placement phase of the next round.